# Full size Bokeh charts as Jupyter slides

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, bokeh, reveal.js, rise

I'm still learning about bokeh and reveal.js, have been impressed with both and so apologies if this is a basic question.

**How can I fully display a bokeh chart on a Jupyter slide without scroll bars appearing?**

Below is an example: 
This chart appears fine in Jupyter as a notebook (note the absence of horizontal scroll bar and the x axis ends at 2015)
[image]

But when converted to slides (via the outstanding RISE) it doesn't fit on the slide (missing years 2012 onward) and a horizontal scroll bar appears.

[image]

**Do i need to set the size of the Bokeh figure? If so, what should it be?**

**or**

**Can I add some metadata code to the Jupyter cell to increase the page size?**

I'm using RISE to automatically create the slide from Jupyter
thanks

Comment: This is probably because crash between css from RISE, reveal.js and Bokeh. Can you open an issue at RISE repo and link the notebook so I can try to figured out the css overlapping? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Damian and apologies for delay in reply, Issue opened https://github.com/damianavila/RISE/issues/162

Answer (score 0):

(disclaimer: I am a founder of Gryd)

Try something like this:
https://beta.gryd.us/notebook/published/dTBiH2W8qCdfj3Qvfd3bNP/Reveal%20+%20Bokeh.ipynb

You have to internally increase the size of the slides and then you can set the height and width parameters on Bokeh plots to fill up the screen (pre-enabled on Gryd). If you clone the notebook, you will see that I also collapse the code cell in the last slide to allow the figure to take up most of the space.

Looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Md723.png)